# Redirect from jQuery modal to non-modal dashboard on log in

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework, redirect, nyromodal

Zend Framework application using jQuery. Login takes place via a nyroModal (jQuery plugin from http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/). Everything works great, validation, etc - but once the user is logged in and Zend_Auth writes the identity I want to redirect to the dashboard. The redirect takes place inside of the modal instead of reloading the browser frame.

Here is the view script of the modal:

```
<?php if($this->login_success) echo $this->login_success; ?>
<div id="login_modal">
<h2>Login</h2>
<?php echo $this->form; ?>
<div class="submit" onclick="submitForm('login')">Log In</div>
</div>
```

Here is my submitForm():

```
function submitForm(thisform) {
    var action = $('#' + thisform + '_form').attr('action');
    var form = $('#' + thisform + '_form').serialize();
    $.post(action, form, function(result) {
        var response = $(result);
        var html = response.filter('div:first').html();
        $('#' + thisform + '_modal').html(html);
    });
}
```

Here is the response from the authController on successful login:

```
$url = $this->view->url(array('controller' => 'billing', 
                              'action' => 'index'), null, null);

$this->view->login_success = '<script type="text/javascript">
                              window.location = "'.$url.'"
                              </script>';
```

I've also tried just using:

```
$this->_helper->redirector('index', 'billing');
```

But that was always loading the dashboard in the modal; now I'm just seeing the Login header and form per the first code block above.

Looking forward to answers to get this modal closed, and user properly redirected to /billing!

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
parent.window.location = "http://your.url.com";
```

I think it's enough.